# Получить данные в определенной дате и заполнить поля

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

я хочу вывести line charts. Где хочу показать прибыль за каждый день по отдельности текущего месяца.
Использую таблицу где есть даты поступления денег и сумма. Проблема в том что для получения charts необходимо заполнить всё поля. Например если взять этот месяц тогда 31 полей. Я хочу вывести данные из таблицы где указаны суммы и даты а если пополнения не было то вывести ноль.
То есть если в базе 5 пополнений в чартах показывается это данные и прикрепляются даты а в остальных полях пишется ноль.

```
var ctxL = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext('2d');
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxL, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [<?php $month = date('t'); for ($i = 1; $i <= $month; $i++) { echo '"' . $i . '",'; } ?>],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Доход",
                    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(245, 245, 245, 0)',
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(220, 0, 48, 1)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 2
                },
                {
                    label: "Расход",
                    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(245, 245, 245, 0)',
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(242, 183, 1, 1)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 2
                },
                {
                    label: "Прибыль",
                    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(245, 245, 245, 0)',
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(15, 79, 168, 1)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 2
                }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                responsive: true
            }
        });
```

Comment: Используйте синтетическую опорную таблицу чисел.

Comment: Это как? Просто я хотел провести циклом, если найдется совпадение в дате вывести если не найдется то проставить нули

Comment: Ну делайте циклом... тоже вариант.

Comment: Только кодом можете подсказать что то не додумываюсь

Comment: https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/